# switch case vs if else

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, compilation, switch-statement

I was wondering if there was any difference in the way the following code was compiled into assembly. I've heard that switch-case is more efficient than if else, but in this example I am not quite sure if that would be the case.

```
if(x==1){
...
}else if(x==2){
...
}else{
...
}
```

and

```
switch(x){
 case 1:
 ...
 break;

 case 2:
 ...
 break;

 default:
 ...
}
```

Comment: Have you considered getting the compiler to emit assembler and compare the resulting code?

Comment: For me swich-case should be avoid and use a [hash](http://hardforo.com/thread-531.html) (associative array) instead. It's cleaner.

Comment: Found a good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028437/why-switch-case-and-not-if-else-if

Comment: Not a fan of spaces, huh? ;)

Answer (score 13):

A compiler will sometimes turn a switch into a jump-table, if the entries are contiguous (or nearly so). Or it could theoretically use a binary search to find the case instead of a linear series of tests, which would be faster if you had a large number of cases.

On the other hand, there's nothing stopping the compiler from doing the same optimisations on the same code converted into if/else.

So on a good compiler, switch can be faster in some cases. On a very good compiler, they'd be the same.

Answer (score 3):

In *this* specific case, the `switch` can be turned into a jump table. The `if` statement (if you write your `=` as `==` :-P) could still do the same thing if the compiler could tell that `x` isn't changing between the `if` clauses (which is usually the case, unless `x` is `volatile` or something).

Answer (score 3):

Note too that the if/else construct can be more efficient if you know certain cases are more likely than others.

Comment: But switch cases are ordered, as well, no?

Comment: I don't know if all compilers guarantee the ordering. Also the compiler may create a jump table -- when this is more or less efficient than if/else is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted as a comment?