# Switch() { case: } performance in C

Tags: c, performance, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Switch/Case and not If/Else If?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028437/why-switch-case-and-not-if-else-if)

I would like to understand how a `switch() case:` statement in C
is translated by the compiler into assembler opcodes.

Specifically, i'm interested in understanding the difference
with a serie of `if then else` branches.

Performance comparison is the main topic.

A few words on vocabulary :
i'm familiar with assembler main concepts, having coded in assembler a long time ago for simpler systems, But certainly do not now anything about x86 assembler semantic.
So a direct assembler output will not be useful.
Pseudo-code is much prefered.

Comment: check this link  http://www.ashishpaliwal.com/blog/2009/08/if-else-vs-switch-%E2%80%93-which-is-better/

Comment: write something then open it in ollydbg, that's the best you can do to really understand it.

Comment: Lot of great answers here. It will be difficult to pick one....

Comment: I do not necessarily agree with the "duplicate" comment imposed on this question. While it's true both questions have some parts in common, the earlier one is much broader (why use switch/case ?), and as such receive answers on many issues, such as cleaner code, easier reading, maintenance, and so on. My question was specifically targeted at Assembler translation from the compiler, and expected impact on performance. A much more precise scope, which was properly answered here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler can decide to implement it as the equivalent series of `if`/`else if` statements, or it may decide to optimize it using a [branch table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table). This depends on several parameters such as the number of branches and the size of minimum range that includes all values you check against.

**Update:** I remember reading somewhere that typically compilers do not bother to create a branch table unless there are at least 4 switch cases or more; Stephane Rouberol's [informative comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531024/switch-case-performance-in-c#comment16871131_12531073) below specifically documents how this threshold can be configured for GCC.

Comment: And "branch table" is? Condition-jump "pairs"?

Comment: @KirilKirov: Just added a relevant link.

Comment: From gcc v4.7.2 release notes: Support for a new parameter --param case-values-threshold=n was added to allow users to control the cutoff between doing switch statements as a series of if statements and using a jump table.

Comment: Thanks. +1, as I was going to answer exactly the same.

Comment: @StephaneRouberol: Thank you for the comment, I incorporated it in the answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on various heuristics in the compiler the code generated can end up being just a simple chain of "if else if" statements. In some situations when the space of cases is small, the compiler can make a jump table, for example:

```
switch (foo) {
case 0:
    a();
case 1:
    b();
case 2:
    c();
case 3:
    d();
default:
    e();
}
```

Can be translated into something like:

```
if (foo < 0 || foo > 3) goto label_default;
else goto internal_jump_table[foo];

internal_jump_table = { label_0, label_1, label_2, label_3 };
label_0: a();
label_1: b();
label_2: c();
label_3: d();
label_default: e();
```

There are other optimizations that can be done. Instead of checking for equality, the compiler can build a hierarchy of if statements to binary search for the right value. Or you maybe have a bunch of values where a jump table is appropriate and a few outliers where normal searching is done. Or maybe just two jump tables.

Comment: Wow, i wasn't aware it was possible to build one's own jump table using your sample C semantic. It looks great

Comment: @Cyan It isn't. This was just pseudocode. There's a gcc extension to take addresses of labels and doing goto to them, but the syntax is different from what I wrote.

Comment: arf, too good to be true... Anyway, your pseudo code clearly expressed your explanation. Thanks

Comment: A complex question : let's assume that, as your example, i've got a switch with 4 values, {0, 1, 2, 3}. And let's assume that i can guarantee to provide only autorised values. Is there a way to avoid the sanity check which seems performed before the jump ? Regards

Comment: I know that in the past gcc at least would skip the check and instead do something more efficient if you were switching on an enum and handled all the cases. But fiddling with it right now I can't get gcc to not check (I used a different processor architecture in the past though). Btw. the lower limit to generate a jump table seems to be 5 cases, 4 just makes a binary search.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's very clear. Rgds

Answer (score 2):

The common response is always "that depends".
The performance may depend on the platform/CPU-type, compiler, the compiler options etc.

I Do think, that given the right circumstances a `switch()` construct will have complexity log(n), where n is the number of `case:` statements. This is acheived by "binary search".

[This page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100473/Something-You-May-Not-Know-About-the-Switch-Statem) has lots of details (focuses on Microsofts compiler, but the general ideas I think apply in general).

Comment: Surely given the right circumstances switch can have complexity O(1).

Comment: Right, if the cases are a sequence with no "holes"... I think. Otherwise you'll have to search.

Comment: I meant, the best case is O(1) if there's a jump table.

Comment: Even if there are holes, the slots for them in the jump table can be filled by jumping to the "default" label or to the end of the switch, as applicable. It's more a question of how big the entire range is (and hence how big the jump table is) rather than whether it's densely populated.

Comment: Right, but that requires the "case" criterias to be in-sequence, doesn't it?

Comment: I mean, you'll have to "scan" the table, if the values are not in sequence, or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Well, if the cases are 1,3,5 and 13, then a 13-entry jump table would work. Or a 5-entry jump table plus a check for the special case of 13, or whatever else the compiler-writer thinks of.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think you're missing something: in the best case the jump table isn't a list of "case, address" pairs, it's just a list of addresses, and the index of the address in the list *is* the value of the case (perhaps minus some offset equal to the value of the smallest case).

Comment: Right, but if the values are 0, 2000, and 92834542 that won't work

Comment: Indeed, the worst case is not `O(1)`, at least not within reasonable code size. The compiler has the advantage that it knows how many cases there are, and their values, so it never has to emit "general" code.

Comment: Okidoki, so I guess I should've phrased it "significant holes" :-)

Comment: The point is, there are a number of different cases, for which there are different solutions, possibly including jump tables, runs of ifs, binary search etc.

Comment: Noone mentioned the possibility to use a hash if the range is large with many holes? This is an interesting alternative to binary search.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a "big enough" number of `switch cases` (enough to let the compiler opt to generate a branch table instead of a simple *if / else if*):

- a switch-case will have constant time (O(1)) access to the correct block of code to be executed,
- while a series `if/else if` statements will have linear time (O(*n*) where *n* is the number of conditions to evaluate (`if` statements), for n >= "big enough")

**Update:** Of course these considerations do not take into account compiler optimization!

Comment: Implementation with `if` should have O(log(n)) time, since one would implement the tests with a binary search (or equivalent; many machines produce a comparison results that allows a three-way distinction: less-than, equal-to, greater-than).

Comment: mmm... not sure, I don't think the compiler is able to do semantic comparison between the condition evaluations of the *if* statements

Comment: Of course it can. The controlling expression of a switch is an integer type, so it is well ordered.

Comment: well, for a switch statement it can do even better than binary search (branch table), but not for if statements where the condition expressions may be unrelated each other.