# Is there any reason to use switch statement instead of strings of if and elseif?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, if-statement, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advantage of switch over if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/advantage-of-switch-over-if-else-statement)
>   [Why the switch statement and not if-else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449273/why-the-switch-statement-and-not-if-else)

The switch statement seems to be totally useless. Anything it can do can be done by if and else if link.

They probably even compile to the same code.

So why bother having it?

The `break` statements in switch drives me crazy and that `label:` format reminds me of goto.

This is for objective-c, c, C++. I am not sure if vb.net has switch statement, but even if it does I must have forgotten because I never use it.

Comment: I believe it exists for readability.

Comment: Same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449273/why-the-switch-statement-and-not-if-else ?

Comment: By your logic, `if` and `else` are useless because switch can accomplish the same work. :/.

Comment: Why have if, switch, while, and for when you can just use goto?

Comment: while is for loop (actually it's useless because we have for)

Comment: That break statement drives me crazy.

Comment: Also that label: format reminds me of goto :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028437/why-switch-case-and-not-if-else-if

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They may well compile to the same code. But the intent is not necessarily to provide better compiled code so much as it is to provide better *source* code.

You can do `while` or `for` loops with `if` and `goto` as well but that doesn't make `while` and `for` useless. Would you rather have:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    doSomethingWith (i);
```

or:

```
    i = 0;
loop12:
    if (! (i < 10))
        goto skip12
    doSomethingWith (i);
    i++;
    goto loop12
skip12:
```

Comment: +1 for "You can do while loops with if and goto as well but that doesn't make while useless."

Answer (score 3):

```
if (color == WHITE)
{
}
else if (color == BLACK)
{
}
else if (color == GREY)
{
}
else if ((color == ORANGE) || (color == GREEN) || (color == BLUE))
{
}
else
{
}
```

vs

```
switch(color)
{
   case WHITE:
       break;
   case BLACK:
       break;
   case GREY:
       break;
   case ORANGE:
   case GREEN:
   case BLUE:
       break;
   default:
       break;
}
```

Isn't the latter more readable and requires lesser key strokes?

---

Apart from readability there's another unique use of switch-case: [Duff's Device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/514118/183120).  This technique exploits the `goto`-ness of `switch-case` coupled with `while`.

```c
void dsend(char* to, char* from, count) {
  int n = (count + 7) / 8;
  switch (count % 8) {
  case 0: do {
      *to = *from++;
      case 7: *to = *from++;
      case 6: *to = *from++;
      case 5: *to = *from++;
      case 4: *to = *from++;
      case 3: *to = *from++;
      case 2: *to = *from++;
      case 1: *to = *from++;
    } while (--n > 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: no the former is more readable and gives developer more freedom to make changes later for specific cases

Comment: I agree that readability is subjective, but I don't understand the freedom part.  Can you please explain how `if` gives more freedom over `switch-case`?

Comment: If you wanted to change the logic in `else if ((color == ORANGE) || (color == GREEN) || (color == BLUE))` for example, it would be easier using the else if.

Answer (score 1):

Performance of switch is same as if and else if blocks in the worst case. It may be better. This has been discussed before: [Advantage of switch over if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/advantage-of-switch-over-if-else-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Pros:

`Switch` offers a better way to write program than `if`

`Switch` works faster than `if` because during execution compiler generates jump table to **decide** which case is satisfied rather than **checking** which case is satisfied!

Cons:

`case` can only have `int` or `char` constants or an expression that evaluates to one of these!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't optimized into a jump table anyway?

Comment: @djechlin it is indeed optimized in every language with jump table...

Comment: and if using if else it's not optimized?