# 'else if' statement always returns true

Tags: java

Whenever I run this program line 69's `else if (room == 6)` statement, it always returns `true`, regardless of the value of room.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdventureTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "";
        int room = 1;

        while (room != 0) {
            if (room == 1) {
                System.out.println("You find yourself in a room. There's a \"blue\" door and a \"red\" door.\nWhich do you choose?");
                choice = keyboard.next();

                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                    room = 2;
                } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")) {
                    room = 3;
                }
            } else if (room == 2) {
                System.out.println("Going through the red door reveals the \"family\" room.\nYou can also go \"back\". What is your choice?");
                choice = keyboard.next();
                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("family")) {
                    room = 4;
                } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("back")) {
                    room = 1;
                }
            } else if (room == 3) {
                System.out.println("You find two new rooms, the \"kitchen\" and the \"bathroom\".\nYou can also go \"back\", What is your choice?");
                choice = keyboard.next();
                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("kitchen")) {
                    room = 5;
                } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("bathroom")) {
                    room = 6;
                } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("back")) {
                    room = 1;
                }
            } else if (room == 4) {
                System.out.println("In the family room you see a tv \"remote\" do you pick it up and turn on the tv, or go \"back\"?");
                choice = keyboard.next();
                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("remote")) {
                    System.out.println("You pick up the remote and turn on the tv. You are immediately engrossed in the rv program.");
                    System.out.println("In fact you are so interested you stay there watching tv until you die of dehydration");
                    room = 0;
                } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("back")) {
                    room = 2;
                }
            } else if (room == 5) {
                System.out.println("In the kitchen you find some \"crackers\", you are pretty hungry and they don't look that old.\nYou can also go \"back\".");
                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("crackers")) {
                    System.out.println("After eating one cracker, you feel the need to have another one, and another , and another, this goes on until you\nhave eaten so much your stomach bursts and you die.");
                    room = 0;
                } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("back")) {
                    room = 3;
                }
            } else if (room == 6) { // line 69
                System.out.println("In the bathroom there is an open \"window\", you can also go \"back\". What is your choice?");
                choice = keyboard.next();
                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("window")) {
                    System.out.println("You climb out the window and drop to the ground. You are free!");
                    room = 0;
                } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("back")) {
                    room = 3;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Game Over.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 69?

Comment: my bad 
    } else if (room == 6){

Comment: its `if/else if` hell....

Comment: Wow, death by cracker consumption. That's harsh.

Comment: You missed out `choice = keyboard.next();` in room 5.

Comment: @Joormatt As a side note, I would suggest using `switch/case` instead of so many `if/else if` statements (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1028463/5870049)).

Comment: Under what conditions does `} else if (room == 6){` always get executed, so far it seems to work okay. You might consider using `Scanner#nextLine` though

Comment: `else if statement(room == 6) always returns true, regardless of the value of room`
I don't believe you. Try debugger.

Comment: Okay, after some playing, `Scanner#next` is causing you some issues, instead, use `Scanner#nextLine`

Comment: Okay, so the `choice = keyboard.next();` seems to have fixed it,although intellij still tells me it will always be true...

Comment: If you implement @khelwood 's suggestion theres nothing wrong with code.

Comment: Okay, it does seem good now, thanks everyone, I will definitely look into those suggestions, curse you intellij!

Comment: damn, that's a really dark story...

Comment: @Paul well thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are changing the value of room in some of the else-if's.  Could that be messing with subsequent else-if blocks?  Try using the switch...case statement.

example:

```
while (room != 0) {
    switch(room) {

        case 1: {
            System.out.println("You find yourself in a room. There's a \"blue\" door and a \"red\" door.\nWhich do you choose?");
            choice = keyboard.next();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("red")) {
                room = 2;
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")) {
                room = 3;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 2: {
            //room==2 code
            break;
        }

        case 3: {
            //etc...
            break; //don't forget to put the "break" before each case's close bracket
        }
    }
}
```

hth :-)

Comment: Just did this, and It helped simplify it and made fixed intellij's issue with it, although its `case n:` not `case:n`

Answer (score 0):

You could make separate methods to handle what happens in each room, then have an array or ArrayList of those methods (eg., called "roomMethod"). Each of those methods returns the next room chosen by the user. then the main code is:

```
  while (room != 0 ) {
    room = roomMethod[room]();
  }
```

Comment: Well I haven't gotten to arrays yet but when I do, I will look back on this, thanks

Comment: @Joormatt that won't work in java. FredK is most likely used to code in javascript.