# How to shorten this code to prevent duplication of code?

Tags: swift, code-duplication

I had this question for quite a bit long. I am trying to visualize the 3 doors problem, just for fun and practice with Swift. So I have:

3 doors, and therefore 3 different IBActions &
3 functions for all doors. These function are all exactly the same, however only the number of the doors are different in each code. So I was wondering, can I shorten this code?:

```
func openSecondChoice(whatDoorIsClickedOn: Int)
    {
        if whatDoorIsClickedOn == 1
        {
            if whatDoorIsClickedOn == doorWithNumber
            {
                UIButtonDoor1.setBackgroundImage( UIImage (named: "doorWithMoney"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
            else
            {
                UIButtonDoor1.setBackgroundImage( UIImage (named: "doorWithGoat"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
        if whatDoorIsClickedOn == 2
        {
            if whatDoorIsClickedOn == doorWithNumber
            {
                UIButtonDoor2.setBackgroundImage( UIImage (named: "doorWithMoney"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
            else
            {
                UIButtonDoor2.setBackgroundImage( UIImage (named: "doorWithGoat"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
        if whatDoorIsClickedOn == 3
        {
            if whatDoorIsClickedOn == doorWithNumber
            {
                UIButtonDoor3.setBackgroundImage( UIImage (named: "doorWithMoney"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
            else
            {
                UIButtonDoor3.setBackgroundImage( UIImage (named: "doorWithGoat"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }
    }
```

Yuk! This code is so ugly! If the user presses on door1 for example, I'm calling the function "openSecondChoise(whatDoorIsClickedOn: 1)". Is there a way to shorten this? Thank you! I do not use classes here, should I use them?

Comment: You should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you start suffixing your variable names with `1`, `2`, `3`, etc., it's time to use an array instead. This is what arrays are for.

With an array `uiButtonDoors` that contains your `UIButtonDoor1`...`UIButtonDoor3`, your function could look like this:

```
func openSecondChoice(whatDoorIsClickedOn: Int) {
    let imageName = whatDoorIsClickedOn == doorWithNumber ? "doorWithMoney" : "doorWithGoat"
    uiButtonDoors[whatDoorIsClickedOn - 1].setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: imageName), for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

Comment: This will crash for `whatDoorIsClickedOn == 3`

Comment: Np. I think your solution - while shorter than mine - is a tad more inconvenient, because OP would need to change the structure of her code outside the method itself... I suppose it's really just a matter of taste here. However, I totally agree on using an array of buttons for cleaner code :)

Comment: Its okay, I am used to change my whole code hehe :) Question for you guys, I already asked it also to the person who gave the last answer, so maybe he already answered it... but you are using this: "let imageName = whatDoorIsClickedOn == doorWithNumber ? "doorWithMoney" : "doorWithGoat" What is this exactly? What does it do? Why do you use "==" instead of "="? I thought you only use "==" when referring, so its more like a "check" function instead of actually changing something. I hope you understand this! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
func openSecondChoice(whatDoorIsClickedOn: Int) {
  let imageName = whatDoorIsClickedOn == doorWithNumber ? "doorWithMoney" : "doorWithGoat"
  let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

  let button: UIButton

  switch whatDoorIsClickedOn {
  case 1:
    button = UIButtonDoor1
  case 2:
    button = UIButtonDoor2
  case 3:
    button = UIButtonDoor3
  default:
    fatalError("Cannot be. Switch must be exhaustive, that's why we need to use 'default' for a switch on Int.")
  }

  button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

For a shorter version check @tuple_cat s answer.

Comment: I used a couple of ternary conditional operators instead of a switch, but the same effect. @tuple_cat has a much better answer.

Comment: Or, instead of the whole switch: `let button = [UIButtonDoor1, UIButtonDoor2, UIButtonDoor3][whatDoorIsClickedOn - 1]`

Comment: Thank you for your time. However, you are saying that tuple_cat has a better answer, so I will look onto that. But a question for you, why use switch statement over an if statement? I searched it up, I got this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028437/why-switch-case-and-not-if-else-if Is it still valid or outdated?

Comment: Sure it's still valid. `switch` is just another tool in your toolbox besides `if-else`. There are many advantages but you should always ponder depending on the use case. However, personally I find myself using `switch` a lot more often since I started coding in Swift. It just feels more natural to the language, especially when you start using pattern matching all over the place :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, for fun.

```
import UIKit

class DoorGame {
    func setupButtons() {
        let buttons = [UIButton(), UIButton(), UIButton()]

        for (index, button) in buttons.enumerated() {
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.setTitle("\(index)", for: .normal)
        }

        let winningIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))

        buttons[winningIndex].tag = 1
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let imageName = sender.tag == 1 ? "doorWithMoney" : "doorWithGoat"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        sender.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is different than the answers above. However thank you for your time. I do not understand all of this, for example: Why use a class here over a function? Why do you use "@objc" before the "fun buttonTapped"? And last: what is " let imageName = sender.tag == 1 ? "doorWithMoney" : "doorWithGoat"" How do you call it? Was does it do? Is it a condition and ":" separates the correct answer from the wrong answer if the condition is met (condition is everything before "?")? Thank you!

Comment: The theme of this answer is to use the `tag` property to embed some data on a button (`tag == 1` means it's the winner), and then to use the touch-up action on the button to alter the background image.  It's in a class because encapsulation is a hallmark of good program design.  `@objc` is an advanced topic so I'll recommend you read about it later.  Normally this code would be in a view controller and you wouldn't need `@objc`, I just wanted this to compile in a Swift playground which is why I included it. `?:` is the conditional operator.  It's a shorthand `if/else` statement. Good luck!