# Unable to compare characters (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple mad libs program in c++, and i want to check and see if a word that a user entered starts with a vowel, and if it does, change the "a" before the word, to an "an". I've been able to get the first character stored, but it will not compare to the other characters in the If statement. Am i doing this completely wrong?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string adj_3;
    string anN;
        char firstChar;

//      GETTING USER'S WORD 

        cout << "ADJECTIVE: " << endl;
        getline(cin, adj_3);

//      GETTING FIRST CHARACTER

        firstChar = adj_3[0];

//      SEEING IF IT'S A VOWEL (not working)

        if(firstChar == ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'A' || 'E' || 'I' || 'O' || 'U')) {
            anN = "n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "not working" << endl;
        }

    cout << "I am having a" << anN << " " << adj_3 << " time at camp." << endl;

}
```

Comment: You might want to read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In it it will show you how to do multiple comparisons.

Comment: That's not how operator|| works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` operator needs to be applied to two arguments, like so:

```
if (firstChar == 'a' || firstChar == 'e' || firstChar == 'i' || ...)
```

`firstChar == 'a'` evaluates to a boolean. `firstChar == 'a' || firstChar == 'e'` takes the two booleans that results from those two operations, and returns another boolean, which is then fed into the next `||` operation as the first argument. In this way you can "chain" the `||` operations until one of them is true, or until they're all false.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) for examples and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[hnefatl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45218888/6594779)'s answer is one way.

You can also use switch case without break statements to check vowel. Something like:

```
switch(firstChar)
{
case 'a':
case 'e':
case 'i':
case 'o':
case 'u':
case 'A':
case 'E':
case 'I':
case 'O': 
case 'U': cout<<"Vowel";
}
```

On top of that `switch-case` have many advantages over `if-else ladder` as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028463/6594779.

Answer (score 1):

Logical operator `||` combines two boolean expressions, e.g. `a==0 || b==1`, and returns true if either of the two operands is `true`. If you pass a single character like `'a'` as operand, this will be interpreted as `true`, since the value of `'a'` is `97` and `97 != 0 => true`. Hence, your expression `('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' || 'A' || 'E' || 'I' || 'O' || 'U')` will always be `true`, and `firstchar == (....)` is the same as `firstchar == true`, which will probably give `false`.

You could write...

```
if (firstChar == 'a' || firstChar == 'e' || firstChar == 'i' || ...)
```

or...

```
if (strchr(firstChar, "aeiouAEIOU") != NULL)) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array too wherein you store all the vowels and then compare it. Something like shown below:

```
   char vowels[10]={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
   int flag=0;
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
       if(vowels[i]==firstChar)
       {
           flag=1;
           anN="n";
       }
   }
   if(flag==1)
        cout << "I am having a" << anN << " " << adj_3 << " time at camp." << endl;
   else
       cout << "not working" << endl;
```